# How can I uninstall Egit feature from Juno?

Tags: eclipse, uninstallation, egit

I am trying to run JUnit test for an eclipse plugin I created. However, the confirmation dialogs from the EGit plugin blocks my perspective from loading up, and hence throws an unnecessary exception on my console for JUnit.
I tried looking for possibility to uninstall the plugin, but did not see any such option.
How can I disable the Egit plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the problem with the confirmation dialog has been fixed in EGit 2.2, which will be released on 2012-12-19, see [bug 391377](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=391377).

In general, it's a good practice to only include the minimally required set of features in the launch configuration. This can be configured in the *Plug-ins* tab of your launch configuration.

To only include certain features, select *features selected below* from the *Launch with* dropdown, check the features which should be included and press on *Add Required Plug-ins*.

Also, it's useful to work with specific target platforms, see the [wiki page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDE/Target_Definitions) or [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseTargetPlatform/article.html).

Comment: Thanks robinst! In the launch configuration for the test, I selected "plugins selected below only" and then unchecked the org.eclipse.egit.* entries, and ... it works, no exceptions (pun intended)!

Answer (score 8):

The plugins are not easy to remove/disable in eclipse. But you can remove jar files of that plugins to remove a plugin.

In Linux or Mac, open the Terminal, and `cd` to eclipse folder.

```
mkdir disabled disabled/features disabled/plugins

mv features/*egit* disabled/features/
mv plugins/*jgit* disabled/plugins/
mv plugins/*egit* disabled/plugins
```

Read more in http://blog.sarathonline.com/2012/05/eclipse-indigo-without-mylyn.html

Comment: This is a Top tip! Totally worked, the only thing a had to do after this was to go into whats already installed in eclipse and remove them from there also, after that egit was GONE!

Answer (score 2):

In Juno:

Windows>Preferences>Install/Update>Uninstall or Update.

Click on plugins you want to remove and click on uninstall

Comment: Not sure if this is evident from my question, but I wanted to disable the Egit plugin in my plguin runtime only, not in my main workspace. The solution provided by robinst works well.

Comment: Not working. "Install"/"Uninstall" buttons inactive. (That's what I hate most with Eclipse: The plugin mess. They seem not aware that some stuff should be removeable - without wasting hours on the hassle. But well, who cares about basic functionality nowadays?)

Answer (score 1):

Hey I found a very easy way to do it, posting it maybe can help someone:

To uninstall the EGit Plugin do the following:

**Help > Eclipse Marketplace... > Installed Tab > EGit > uninstall**

Comment: Doesn't work for me .. even if I clicked uninstall and the Eclipse got restarted, that plugin was still there.

Answer (score -1):

on mac

```
mkdir disabled disabled/features disabled/plugins

mv features/*egit* disabled/features/
mv plugins/*jgit* disabled/plugins/
mv plugins/*egit* disabled/plugins
```

did not solve anything.

After doing that, and after a marketplace-uninstall egit was already to uninstall...

Congrats eGit.