# Can't uninstall EGit from Eclipse LUNA

Tags: eclipse, plugins, uninstallation, egit, eclipse-luna

EGit plugin is crashing Eclipse time and again, because apparently it gets stuck not being able to connect to the repository (which in facts is unreachable).

I tried to uninstall the plugin many times but it is not being uninstalled:

I followed the sequence Help -> Eclipse Marketplace -> Installed -> EGit -> Uninstall,
then I tried both selecting everything or just one of the items (Eclipse Git Team Provider, Java Implementation of Git), Confirmed and clicked Finish and acknowledged the restart.

Every time I go back in the Eclipse Marketplace, the Egit plugin is still installed. And in facts it crashes Eclipse once more.

Has anyone any suggestion to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: which eclipse version you are using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I uninstall Egit feature from Juno?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917352/how-can-i-uninstall-egit-feature-from-juno)

Answer (score 2):

I used the second answer from the following post and it worked for me:

[How can I uninstall Egit feature from Juno?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917352/how-can-i-uninstall-egit-feature-from-juno)

```
mkdir disabled disabled/features disabled/plugins

mv features/*egit* disabled/features/
mv plugins/*jgit* disabled/plugins/
mv plugins/*egit* disabled/plugins
```

Even though the answer was for Juno, I can confirm that this works flawlessly on Luna on Mac OSX.

Cheers!

Comment: Confirmed for Luna on Windows 10 with Git Bash